# Read txt file and create users with specific prefix and add additional parameters

Tags: windows, cmd

I was wondering how to make script which takes **Prefix** and **txt file** in which I have full name(/fullname), comment(/comment) and work days(/times)

For example:
I call this script like this: `F:\Destination>UserScript.cmd Profile Log.txt` Where Profile - prefix for all users and Log.txt with additional parameters like these below!

```
"Bob Truman", "Test Comment", "M"
"Sarah Hanks", "Test Comment", "M-S"
```

Should be created

```
    Profile1 /fullname:"Bob Truman" /comment="Test comment" /times="M"
    Profile2 /fullname:"Sarah Hanks" /comment:"Test comment" /times:"M-S"
```

Here what I have tried so far: (%1 Profile, %2 Log.txt)

```
For /F "delims= " %%i in (%2) do (
net user "%1%%i" "%1%%i" /logonpasswordchg:yes /add /fullname:"%%b" /comment:"%%c" /times:"%%d"
```

Comment: At the moment `%1` is `Sarah`, and `%5` is `M-S`. But if a name is not in two parts, a comment has a different number of distinct words, or even if somebody works `M,W,F` all of those `%n` will shift around. It will only work if you pass the parameters by doublequoting them or separating each with an otherwise unused character, _(less robust)_. If you use doublequotes, ```"Sarah Hanks" "Test Comment" "M-S"``` or ```"Sarah Hanks","Test Comment","M-S"```, or even ```"Sarah Hanks", "Test Comment", "M-S"```, then you'll almost always be able to utilise `%1`,`%2`, and `%3` as needed.

Comment: @Compo, thanks a lot, but how would look for loop with your suggestions?

Comment: We would need more information about how you are providing the arguments to the script to be able to assist you with a specific methodology. Please use the [Edit] button and update your question accordingly.

Comment: You need to still change the format of your text file. It's great that you're now using a unique comma separator, but you should remove the spaces which follow each of them, or as I mentioned before doublequote each individually wanted string.

Comment: @Compo I think I understood you correctly, I edited it again

Comment: So now you could use ```For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1-3" %%G In ("%~1") Do For /F %%J In ("%%~G") Do ...```. Where `%~1` is `Profile Log.txt`, and if `%%~G` is `Sarah Hanks`, `%%~H` will be `Test Comment`, `%%~I` will be `M-S`, and `%%~J` will be`Sarah`.

Comment: @Compo thanks, but this stuff create Profile"Sarah Hanks", while I need Profile1 and fullname as additional parameter, but anyway thanks so much I will figure it out :)